# Encoding and decoding between Javascript and c#

Tags: c#, javascript, encoding

I want to be able to send data to Javascript in a div like this:

```
<div class="dontDisplay><%= myData %></div>
```

However, the challenge is that the HTML will get messed up. There seems to be a plethora of encoding and decoding schemes out there, but  I can't find a javascript/C# pair that are guaranteed to be compatible for all possible inputs (including Unicode.)

Does anyone know of a pair that are known to be perfectly compatible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You most probably want to use [json](http://www.json.org/js.html). You can embed a string in your page that creates a local variable on your page using json inside a script-tag:

```
<script> var myJsonVariabe = { propertyNane: "value" }; </script>
```

You can serialize a .net object to json using the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be just putting some text into HTML text content, for which the correct approach is plain old HTML-encoding:

```
<div class="dontDisplay"><%= Server.HTMLEncode(myData) %></div>
```

or in ASP.NET 4.0:

```
<div class="dontDisplay"><%: myData %></div>
```

If JavaScript needs to extract this, you can use DOM methods:

```
<div id="foo"><%= Server.HTMLEncode(myData) %></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myData= document.getElementById('foo').firstChild.data;
</script>
```

although this assumes that there's exactly one text node in there, and will break if `myData` is an empty string. You can work around this by having a `getTextContent` method that checks all the `childNodes` for being text nodes and adds their `data` together, or use `textContent` with fallback to `innerText` for IE, or use a library to do it (eg. `text()` in jQuery).

alternatively you can put the data in an attribute:

```
<div id="foo" title="<%= Server.HTMLEncode(myData) %>">...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myData= document.getElementById('foo').title;
</script>
```

if there is a suitable attribute available (`title` might not be appropriate), or a comment, or directly into a JavaScript variable using JSON as suggested by Rune.

Comment: Thanks for the help, what I need to understand is that once the text is encoded with HTMLEncode, how do I unencode it on the JavaScript side? So, using the above, I pass in:

    Hello&Hello

It is encoded as Hello&amp;Hello Now I want a Javascript string as "Hello&Hello". How to decode the HTMLEncoded string, with some guarantee that every encoding in HTMLEncode will translate correctly on the Javascript side.

Comment: You do not need to unencode it. When you use `textnode.data`, `element.textContent`, `element.innerText` or `element.getAttribute`, you get the pure text content without any markup, which will result in `Hello&Hello`. It's only `innerHTML` that gives you HTML-encoded markup—and not necessarily the same markup you put in. So don't use that.